# How to interpret grouping result in Tukey's HSD test

Tags: multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

Assuming there are three methods to kill bugs, and we want to know whether their performance differs. The Tukey's HSD test gives the following grouping results:

```
$groups
  trt means  M
1   1  1.96  a
2   3  1.88 ab
3   2  1.68  b
```

If we need suggest some methods to use, can we say method 1 and 3 can both be used as they are either better than or equal to method 2 (both have the grouping letter 'a')?

Comment: What is the actual scientific question here? What are you going to use the treatments for?

Answer (score 1):

You would not be able to say that.

Since `treatment 3` shares a subscript with `treatment 2`, `treatment 3` is not more than the expected standard error greater than `treatment 2`.

Basically, at an alpha of .05, we would expect a false positive 1 out of every 20 times we collect the data. Values that share a subscript mean this result would occur more than 1 out of every 20 times we collect the data.

You would be able to conclude, however, that `treatment 1` is significantly greater than `treatment 2`.